# How to access a multi Dimensional PHP Array in javascript as json-encoded variant?

Tags: php, javascript, json, multidimensional-array

After asking a question yesterday, I've learned that I need to have an array in Php and use JSON to pass it to Javascript. I've got all that working up to a point, but I need to add one more dimension to my array and not sure how.

The current array is:

```
$result = array(
  'NumberSelected' => $number,
  'TargetPerc'     => array (),
  'KpiDescription' => array (),
  'KpiName'        => array (),
  'ValuetoPrint'   => array (),
  'ValueNow'       => array (),
  'ValueCompare'   => array (),
  'Target'         => array (),
  'KpiUnits'       => array ()
);
```

But I now need to enclose this in another dimension to sort these by group.

This is what I've tried:

```
$result = array(
  $i => array(
    'NumberSelected' => $number,
    'TargetPerc'     => array (),
    'KpiDescription' => array (),
    'KpiName'        => array (),
    'ValuetoPrint'   => array (),
    'ValueNow'       => array (),
    'ValueCompare'   => array (),
    'Target'         => array (),
    'KpiUnits'       => array ()
  )
);
```

With `$i` defined as 0 two lines before that. But it doesn't seem to recognise the outermose array. Could be something to do with my collecting code which is `result.KpiName[i]` currently (the JSON variable is passed to this javascript function as `result`). And I've tried `result.i[KpiName[i]]` with no success.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: wow. even with the code highlighted, that's really hard to read.

Comment: Sorry, had copied it straight out of the file, looks better now though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a single result:

```
$result = array(
    'NumberSelected' => $number,
    'TargetPerc' => array(),
    ....
);
```

Then you want to add it in with some other results:

```
$result_set = array();
$result_set[] = $result;
```

At this point, `$result_set` is an array with one element, an array containing keys `'NumberSelected'`, `'TargetPerc'`, etc.

I think you are getting tripped up with the idea of having arrays in arrays in arrays, so think of it like this: each array index is a component of an "path" to a specific piece of data, like in a filesystem. In this case, `$result_set` is the most general piece of the "path", like a drive letter on Windows. Inside our pretend drive are a bunch of folders named with numbers, so `$result_set[0]` is the first folder, `$result_set[1]` would be the second. In each of those folders are sub-folders called `NumberSelected` (actually that one would be like a file, since it has a scalar value), `TargetPerc`, etc, which correspond to the second layer of your result set: `$result_set[0]['NumberSelected']`. Now, the final dimension of your array corresponds to the individual files inside each of `'TargetPerc'`, `'KpiDescription'`, etc, where the files, unless you gave them named keys, are named with numbers.

So, to access the first item of `'KpiDescription'` in the first result in your result set, your filesystem "path" (keeping with the analogy) would be

```
result_set/0/KpiDescription/0
```

Now, translating it back to PHP:

```
$result_set[0]['KpiDescription'][0]
```

Easy, right?

Now the JSON part of your question: once you `json_encode` it, it's just going to look like a big string of text to PHP, but the magic thing about `json_encode` is that it maintains the original data structure, but in Javascript.

So your result set would look like this:

```
result_set = [
    {
        NumberSelected: 123,
        TargetPerc: [ ... ],
        KpiDescription: [ ... ]
    }
];
```

As you can see, the Javascript is just an array of objects, where each object has some properties that happen to be arrays. To access the first item in the first `KpiDescription` (just like above), you would use this:

```
result_set[0].KpiDescription[0]
```

Alternatively, because Javascript allows you to treat object properties as array indexes (actually that's not *quite* true, but that's another story), you could do this:

```
result_set[0]['KpiDescription'][0]
```

Look familiar? All it's missing from the PHP is the leading `$`.

I hope that helps clear some things up for you.

Comment: Thanks for the well thought out answer. Got it to pass correctly, so can build the rest of it now. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set $i, `$arr = array(array(array()));` is enough to init 3D array.

Your code should work with `result[i]['KpiName'][i]`

/**Edit**: added quotation marks. Tested it with syntax above, should work.
Tested with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var arr = new Array();
    arr[0] = new Array();
    arr[0]['test'] = new Array();
    arr[0]['test'][1] = 5;

    alert(arr[0]['test'][1]);
});
```

returned 5 as expected

Comment: Thanks, but I need to collect the results in javascript. The arrays passed as a JSON variable using onClick function to a javascript function and its there that I need to output the values.

Comment: aren't you decoding JSON with eval()? If not, then try result.i.KpiName.j ?

Comment: Passing the JSON to a javascript variable, not decoding it at any stage, so previously I was using `result.KpiName[i]` which worked fine before the extra dimension.

Comment: Doesn't that miss quotes araound `KpiName` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array(
  'NumberSelected' => $number,
  'TargetPerc'     => array (),
  'KpiDescription' => array (),
  'KpiName'        => array (),
  'ValuetoPrint'   => array (),
  'ValueNow'       => array (),
  'ValueCompare'   => array (),
  'Target'         => array (),
  'KpiUnits'       => array ()
);

$newArray[0] = $result;
```

is the simplest answer I can think of unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

The actual collecting code will be:-

```
$result[i][KpiName][j]
```

where "`i`" & "`j`" are indices of the above array.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Doesn't that miss quotes araound `KpiName` ?

Comment: I'm collecting in Javascript. The array is passed as a variable using `json_encode($result)` and I'm trying to output in javascript. Originally I used `result.KpiName[i]` to output and it worked correctly, not sure with the extra dimension though.